# How to create a precision-recall curve plot to compare 2 classifiers in Python?

Tags: python, plot, logistic-regression, random-forest, precision-recall

My goal is to find the precision-recall curve, comparing with Logistic Regression and Random Forest and plotting them in one graph. I wanted to know if I used the right steps to create a plot to compare both classifiers.
I appreciate all the help!

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer as mlb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from matplotlib import pyplot

X = df[["DIAGNOSIS_CD_Dummy"]]
y = df[["TEST_RESULT_Dummy"]]
# X = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, -1])
# y = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, :-1])

# raw confusion matrix
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=["DIAGNOSIS_CD_Dummy", "TEST_RESULT_Dummy"])
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(
    df["TEST_RESULT_Dummy"],
    df["DIAGNOSIS_CD_Dummy"],
    rownames=["Test Result"],
    colnames=["Diagnosis"],
)
print(confusion_matrix)


# Logistic Regression Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer as mlb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn import metrics


# split into training and test using scikit
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y.values.ravel(), test_size=0.3, random_state=1, stratify=y
)
log_model = LogisticRegression()
log_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# use logistic regression model to make predictions
y_score = log_model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

y_pred = log_model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.round(y_pred)
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print("\n")
print(confusion_matrix)
print("\n")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, zero_division=0))

# calculate precision and recall
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_score)

# create precision recall curve
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(recall, precision, color="purple")

# add axis labels to plot
ax.set_title("Precision-Recall Curve")
ax.set_ylabel("Precision")
ax.set_xlabel("Recall")

# display plot
plt.show()

# precision-recall curve
# generate 2 class dataset
X = df[["DIAGNOSIS_CD_Dummy"]]
y = df[["TEST_RESULT_Dummy"]]

# X = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, :-1])
# y = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, -1])

# split into train/test sets
trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(
    X, y.values.ravel(), test_size=0.3, random_state=2
)
# fit a model
model = LogisticRegression(solver="lbfgs")
model.fit(trainX, trainy)

# predict probabilities
lr_probs = model.predict_proba(testX)
# probs_rf = model_rf.predict_proba(testX)[:, 1]

# keep probabilities for the positive outcome only
lr_probs = lr_probs[:, 1]

# predict class values
yhat = model.predict(testX)
lr_precision, lr_recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(testy, lr_probs)
lr_f1, lr_auc = f1_score(testy, yhat), auc(lr_recall, lr_precision)

# precision_rf, recall_rf, _ = precision_recall_curve(testy, probs_rf)
# f1_rf, auc_rf = f1_score(testy, yhat), auc(recall_rf, precision_rf)
# auc_rf = auc(recall_rf, precision_rf)


# summarize scores
print("Logistic: f1=%.3f auc=%.3f" % (lr_f1, lr_auc))

# plot the precision-recall curves
no_skill = len(testy[testy == 1]) / len(testy)
pyplot.plot([0, 1], [no_skill, no_skill], linestyle="--", label="No Skill")
pyplot.plot(lr_recall, lr_precision, marker=".", label="Logistic")

plt.plot(lr_precision, lr_recall, label=f"AUC (Logistic Regression) = {lr_auc:.2f}")

# axis labels
pyplot.xlabel("Recall")
pyplot.ylabel("Precision")
# show the legend
pyplot.legend()
# show the plot
pyplot.show()



# Random Forest
model_rf = RandomForestClassifier()
model_rf.fit(trainX, trainy)
# model_rf = RandomForestClassifier().fit(trainX, trainy)

# predict probabilities
lr_probs = model.predict_proba(testX)
probs_rf = model_rf.predict_proba(testX)

# keep probabilities for the positive outcome only
probs_rf = probs_rf[:, 1]

# predict class values
yhat = model.predict(testX)
precision_rf, recall_rf, _ = precision_recall_curve(testy, probs_rf)
f1_rf, auc_rf = f1_score(testy, yhat), auc(recall_rf, precision_rf)
auc_rf = auc(recall_rf, precision_rf)

print("Random Forest: f1=%.3f auc=%.3f" % (f1_rf, auc_rf))

# plot the precision-recall curves
no_skill = len(testy[testy == 1]) / len(testy)
pyplot.plot([0, 1], [no_skill, no_skill], linestyle="--", label="No Skill")
pyplot.plot(lr_recall, lr_precision, marker=".", label="Random Forest")

plt.plot(recall_rf, precision_rf, label=f"AUC (Random Forests) = {auc_rf:.2f}")

# axis labels
pyplot.xlabel("Recall")
pyplot.ylabel("Precision")
# show the legend
pyplot.legend()
# show the plot
pyplot.show()
```

Output:

```
Diagnosis        0    1
Test Result            
0            18385   32
1             1268  165


[[5514   11]
 [ 374   56]]


              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.94      1.00      0.97      5525
           1       0.84      0.13      0.23       430

    accuracy                           0.94      5955
   macro avg       0.89      0.56      0.60      5955
weighted avg       0.93      0.94      0.91      5955
```

Logistic: f1=0.193 auc=0.488

[image: Logistic]

Random Forest: f1=0.193 auc=0.488

[image: Random Forest]

Answer (score 2):

This is my attempt to plot it.

```py
import pathlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator)
from sklearn.metrics import PrecisionRecallDisplay
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
from itertools import cycle
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize

def __plot_binary_precision_recall_curve(X_test, y_test, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Private function to be used by plot_precision_recall_curve for binary applications.
    """

    if 'fig_size' in kwargs and 'dpi' in kwargs:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=kwargs['fig_size'], dpi=kwargs['dpi'])
    else:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    plt.rcParams["figure.facecolor"] = 'white'
    plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = 'white'
    plt.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"] = 'white'

    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.1f}')

    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.1f}')

    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.05))
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.05))

    ax.tick_params(which='both', width=2)
    ax.tick_params(which='major', length=7)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='black')

    plt.grid(True, zorder=0)
    plt.plot([0, 1], [1, 0], linestyle='--', lw=1, color='k',
             label='Luck', alpha=.8, zorder=1) # random prediction curve
    plt.plot([1, 1], [1, 0], c='k', linestyle='dashdot'), plt.plot([1, 1], c='k', linestyle='dashdot', zorder=2, label="Perfect model") #perfect model prediction curve

    f_scores = np.linspace(0.2, 0.8, num=4)
    lines, labels = [], []
    for f_score in f_scores:
        x = np.linspace(0.01, 1)
        y = f_score * x / (2 * x - f_score)
        (l,) = plt.plot(x[y >= 0], y[y >= 0], color="gray", alpha=0.2)
        plt.annotate("f1={0:0.1f}".format(f_score), xy=(0.9, y[45] + 0.02))

    zorder = 3
    for classifier in args:
        display = PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_estimator(classifier, X_test, y_test, ax=ax, zorder=zorder)
        zorder +=1

    # add the legend for the iso-f1 curves
    handles, labels = display.ax_.get_legend_handles_labels()
    handles.extend([l])
    labels.extend(["iso-f1 curves"])
    # set the legend and the axes
    ax.set_xlim([0.0, 1.0])
    ax.set_ylim([0.0, 1.05])
    ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc="best")

    plt.xlabel('Recall', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Precision', fontsize=18)

    if 'title' in kwargs:
        ax.set_title(kwargs['title'], fontsize=18)
    else:
        ax.set_title("Precision-Recall Curve", fontsize=18)

    if 'save_fig_path' in kwargs:
        path = pathlib.Path(kwargs['save_fig_path'])
        path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        fig.savefig(kwargs['save_fig_path'], dpi=kwargs['dpi'], facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), edgecolor='none')

    return fig, ax

def __plot_multiclass_precision_recall_curve(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Private function designed to be used by plot_precision_recall_curve for multiclass applications.
    """

    my_vals = y_test.unique().tolist()
    my_vals.sort()

    # binarize the y_test series
    y_test = label_binarize(y_test, classes=my_vals)

    n_classes = y_test.shape[1]

    # setup plot details
    colors = cycle(["navy", "turquoise", "darkorange", "cornflowerblue", "teal"])

    if 'fig_size' in kwargs and 'dpi' in kwargs:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(args), figsize=kwargs['fig_size'], dpi=kwargs['dpi'], facecolor='white')
    else:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(args), facecolor='white')

    for count, clfs in enumerate(args):

        ax[count].xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
        ax[count].xaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.1f}')

        ax[count].yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
        ax[count].yaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.1f}')

        ax[count].xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.05))
        ax[count].yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.05))

        ax[count].tick_params(which='both', width=2)
        ax[count].tick_params(which='major', length=7)
        ax[count].tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='black')

        ax[count].grid(True, zorder=0)
        ax[count].plot([0, 1], [1, 0], linestyle='--', lw=1, color='k',
             label='Luck', alpha=.8, zorder=1) # random prediction curve
        ax[count].plot([1, 1], [1, 0], c='k', linestyle='dashdot'), ax[count].plot([1, 1], c='k', linestyle='dashdot', zorder=2, label="Perfect model") #perfect model prediction curve

        # set up the model, wrapped by the OneVsRestClassifier
        classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(clfs)
        classifier.fit(X_train, y_train) # train the model

        # produce the predictions (as probabilities)
        y_score = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)

        # For each class
        precision = dict()
        recall = dict()
        average_precision = dict()
        for i in range(n_classes):
            precision[i], recall[i], _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
            average_precision[i] = average_precision_score(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])

        # A "micro-average": quantifying score on all classes jointly
        precision["micro"], recall["micro"], _ = precision_recall_curve(
            y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel()
        )
        average_precision["micro"] = average_precision_score(y_test, y_score, average="micro")

        f_scores = np.linspace(0.2, 0.8, num=4)
        lines, labels = [], []
        for f_score in f_scores:
            x = np.linspace(0.01, 1)
            y = f_score * x / (2 * x - f_score)
            (l,) = ax[count].plot(x[y >= 0], y[y >= 0], color="gray", alpha=0.2)
            ax[count].annotate("f1={0:0.1f}".format(f_score), xy=(0.9, y[45] + 0.02))

        display = PrecisionRecallDisplay(
            recall=recall["micro"],
            precision=precision["micro"],
            average_precision=average_precision["micro"],
            )
        display.plot(ax=ax[count], name="Micro-average precision-recall", color="gold")

        for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
            display = PrecisionRecallDisplay(
                recall=recall[i],
                precision=precision[i],
                average_precision=average_precision[i],
            )
            display.plot(ax=ax[count], name=f"Precision-recall for class {i}", color=color)

        # add the legend for the iso-f1 curves
        handles, labels = display.ax_.get_legend_handles_labels()
        handles.extend([l])
        labels.extend(["iso-f1 curves"])
        # set the legend and the axes
        ax[count].set_xlim([0.0, 1.0])
        ax[count].set_ylim([0.0, 1.05])
        ax[count].legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc="best")

        if type(clfs) == Pipeline:
            estimator_name = str(type(clfs['clf'])).split(".")[-1][:-2]
        else:
            estimator_name = str(type(clfs)).split(".")[-1][:-2]

        if 'title' in kwargs:
            ax[count].set_title(kwargs['title'] + " - " + estimator_name, fontsize=18)
        else:
            ax[count].set_title("Precision-Recall Curve" + " - " + estimator_name, fontsize=18)

        ax[count].set_xlabel('Recall', fontsize=18)
        ax[count].set_ylabel('Precision', fontsize=18)

        if 'save_fig_path' in kwargs:
            path = pathlib.Path(kwargs['save_fig_path'])
            path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            fig.savefig(kwargs['save_fig_path'], dpi=kwargs['dpi'], facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), edgecolor='none')

    return fig, ax


def plot_precision_recall_curve(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Plots precision recall curves for the given models

    Parameters
    ----------
    X_test : pandas.DataFrame of shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Test values.
    y_test : pandas.Series of shape (n_samples,)
        Target values.
    *args : estimators to plot precision and recall curves
        estimator instance (either sklearn.Pipeline, imblearn.Pipeline or a classifier)
        PRE-FITTED classifier or a PRE-FITTED Pipeline in which the last estimator is a classifier.
    **kwargs : The following options are available with kwargs
        fig_size : tuple
            Size (inches) of the plot.
        dpi : int, default = 100
            Image DPI.
        title : str
            The title of the plot.
        save_fig_path : str
            Full path where to save the plot. Will generate the folders if they don't exist already.

    Returns
    -------
        fig : Matplotlib.pyplot.Figure
            Figure from matplotlib
        ax : Matplotlib.pyplot.Axe
            Axe object from matplotlib

    Example Syntax
    --------------
    fig, ax = reporting.plot_precision_recall_curve(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test,
                            rf_pipe, catboost_classifier,
                            fig_size=(10,16), dpi=100,
                            title="Precision-Recall Curve",
                            save_fig_path="dir1/dir2/precision_recall_curve.png")

    """

    if (len(y_test.unique()) == 2):
        fig, ax = __plot_binary_precision_recall_curve(X_test, y_test, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        fig, ax = __plot_multiclass_precision_recall_curve(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, *args, **kwargs)

    return fig, ax
```

- Syntax and Output for Binary Classification

```py
fig, ax = plot_precision_recall_curve(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test,
               rf_pipe, xgboost_classifier,
               fig_size=(10,8), dpi=100,
               title="Precision-Recall Curve",
               save_fig_path="dir1/dir2/precision_recall_curve.png")
```

[image]

- Syntax and Output for Multi-class Classification

```py
fig, ax = plot_precision_recall_curve(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test,
              rf_pipe, catboost_classifier,
              fig_size=(10,16), dpi=100,
              title="Precision-Recall Curve",
              save_fig_path="dir1/dir2/precision_recall_curve.png")
```

[image]